# Windows Authentication not working with ASP.NET webpage

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I'm trying to hit my intranet website and get it to run a simple sql query as the windows user I'm logged in as.

When I debug through Visual Studio, everything works great. When I hit the webserver though, I get an error from sqlconnection saying, "ERROR:Login failed for user 'YOUR_DOMAIN\YOUR_WEBSERVER_NAME'."

```
Request.ServerVariables[AUTH_USER]: YOUR_DOMAIN\UserBob 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
Page.User.Identity.Name: YOUR_DOMAIN\UserBob
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name: YOUR_DOMAIN\UserBob
```

So how do I get the SQL query to execute under UserBob?

Here's my setup:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
```

Webserver is a Win 2008 server with IIS7, Windows Authentication on, Anon Auth off.

Code is simply:

```
Response.Write("Request.ServerVariables[AUTH_USER]: " + Request.ServerVariables ["AUTH_USER"].ToString());
Response.Write("<br>System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
Response.Write("<br>Page.User.Identity.Name: " + Page.User.Identity.Name);
Response.Write("<br>System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name: " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CarbonDB"].ConnectionString);

conn.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand("dbo.runsomething", conn);
sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();

conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the SQL Server on a different machine than the web server?

If so, the issue you are running into is related to Kerberos Delegation. Basically, your web server doesn't have the permission/ability to impersonate the end user to another server.

[Try this link for more information on delegation.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/df979570-81f6-4586-83c6-676bb005b13e.mspx?mfr=true)

Be aware that this isn't trivial, and requires assistance from a network admin, as it involves making changes to your Active Directory environment.

If possible, use a service account (such as Network Service) to access the SQL Server.

Erick

Comment: SQL Server is on a different machine. Thing is, if I set the authentication to ASP.NET impersonation and hardcode my own creds, it'll work when I hit the webserver from my desktop. Does that still count?

Comment: If you hardcode your own creds, then you aren't doing multiple hops (i.e., delegation) any more, you are directly connecting from one machine to another (IIS to SQL). The problem is that if you use integrated security, the creds actually flow from the browser, not the server.

Answer (score 0):

Is the site using Integrated or Classic pipeline mode. In IIS7, check the Basic Settings of the website, click <kbd>Connect As...</kbd> and make sure that Application user (pass-through authentication) is checked.

Comment: App Pool is Integrated pipeline. Yup, pass-through auth was checked.